# Extracting name and email out of a From email header in PHP

Tags: php, string, parsing, split

I am parsing emails with PHP. I have gotten the parser done, but now I was curious if there's any simple ways to go about extracting both the name and email out of a From header such as below:

**From:** `John Doe <john.doe@hotmail.com>`

Is there a shortcut to getting `John Doe` and `john.doe@hotmail.com` separate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try a regular expression using [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

```
/From:\s*(.*[^\s])\s*<\s*(.*[^\s])\s*>/
```

That should get you the name and email address in index one and two.

Answer (score 0):

There's `mailparse` PECL extension you could try to use if you can have it installed. If not, extract `From:` header and parse it. sender's name is optional, so it may not be there, but email should (beware of spammers though). See [RFC 822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc822.txt) and [RFC 2822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt) for more details

Comment: I am using mailparse. But it gave me a complete header, "Name <Email>"

Comment: In general it's either "FOO <email>" or "<email>" (so sharp brackets are **always** there). Also (usually spammers) can put more addresses in From:, but then it is separated by ","